# GORM/Grails - add extra column to a joinTable expression

Tags: grails, join, grails-orm, lookup-tables

I have a Domain Class setup similar to this

```
class NewsStory {
  String headline
  static hasMany = [channels:Channel]
  static mapping = {
      table 'NewsStory'
      addresses joinTable:[name:'Article_Channel', key:'ArticleId', column:'ChannelId']
  }
}
```

in the Article_Channel table i need to have an extra column populated called ArticleType say. Its value will always be the same e.g. 'news' for this domain class, but will be differnt for others e.g. 'blog' 
Channel is just something like 'Security' etc

Is there a way?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be be to create your own many-to-many mapping class and add the field in there.

http://grails.org/Many-to-Many+Mapping+without+Hibernate+XML

So, for example:

```
class ArticleChannel {
    NewsStory newsStory
    Channel channel
    String articleType
}
```

Then, your `NewsStory` and `Channel` classes would `hasMany` the `ArticleChannel` class.

Comment: Thanks for this. How do you get around the chicken egg situation of needing the article to create the articlechannel item before the item is created i.e. the item is not available for the articlechannel yet?

Comment: I thought i might be able to specify a composite key on the NewsStory of id and articleType, but it doesnt propogate that to the lookup table

Comment: For persisting an ArticleChannel link before an Article is created, you could set the article property as nullable:true.  You'll just need to program your code to remember the ArticleChannel object id to populate it with the article object later.  As for a composite id across a 1-m relationship, I don't think that is possible, and if it is, I'm not sure how.