# Many to many relationship in grails and status of each record

Tags: grails

I have 2 domain models having many to many relation with themselves

```
Candidate{
   String name
   static hasMany = [positions:Position]
}

Position{

   static hasMany = [candidates:Candidate]
   static belongsTo = [Candidate]
}
```

my requirement is to fetch the shortlisted status of each candidate for each position, but grails create the intermediate table itself so any idea how to implement it.

Any comments,ideas,examples will appreciated.

Comment: `Set<Candidate> candidates` is redundant. hasMany datatypes are Sets by default.

Comment: thanks james for ur comment but any idea to achieve the requirement.. i will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

If the status is to be stored on the relationship you could create a mapping domain class for the relationship like described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877197/901257).

The statuses could then be retrieved by (assuming a CandidatePosition class name):

```
def candidatePositionList = CandidatePosition.findAllByCandidate(candidateInstance)
candidatePositionList.each {
    it.position.name // Position name
    it.status        // Status of candidate for Position
}
```